# The Type DefaultConventionScanner must be Convertible to ITypeScanner, StructureMap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap

I've tried googling this in many ways and somehow this is the first generic seeming error message I haven't been able to find ANY results for.

Anyway, I'm upgrading my StructureMap to the newest version (I'm not sure what the last one I had installed was I'm afraid) and I keep getting the error: `Error    1   The type 'StructureMap.Graph.DefaultConventionScanner' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'StructureMap.Graph.IAssemblyScanner.With<T>()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'StructureMap.Graph.DefaultConventionScanner' to 'StructureMap.Graph.ITypeScanner'.`.

The code that's causing the problem is:

```
Scan(scanner =>
            {
                scanner.Assembly(typeof(PersonService).Assembly);
                scanner.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IEntityService<>));
                scanner.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IRootEntityService<>));
                scanner.With<DefaultConventionScanner>(); // This line
            });
```

Anyone have any ideas / experience with this sort of problem?

Comment: Did you try scanner.WithDefaultConventions()?

Comment: I did after I made the post as no responses were coming up :) I was going to set it as the answer in a few days, but since you got it you can have the points :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked it out now, it should be replaced with `scanner.WithDefaultConventions()`;